# New version of XAMPP giving error without message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have recently updated my `XAMPP` with new version **`[5.6.14]`** in `Windows`.
In that new version i'm getting error while using it as shown in following two images,

## Problem-1:

When I click on any table name on the left side panel to view its contents sometime i get this error message:

> 'Some errors have been detected on the server!
>
> Please look at the bottom of this window.'

**Undefined variable 'pack_keys', seems like a PMA bug**

This error has been captured in screenshot that i have been attached you may have look at it.

If I click on popup's 'Ignore' button the content reloads well formatted without any problem. I am not getting this error at particular event or situation it occurs randomly.

[image: screenshot_ignore_error]

## Problem-2:

In some situation in notification bar arrives without any message while in most cases either

> `Loading...`

or any other message are there in notification bar but i have shown in **screenshot - 2** in which no message is there in bar and previous event operation is cancelled as per my observation.

In most case when i try to give relation in table or creating column in table after completing operation when click on save button it gives this and after that again all the relations has to give again as operation not executed or create column as they are not created so it is very frustrating for any developer to do that thing again.

I have install this new version two weeks before other things are working fine but these are the some issues that i have face please help me if anyone have solution of this or let me know if you are facing this same issue...

**PHP Version -> 5.6.14**

**Apache Version -> Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.14**

This program is under the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies as specified in phpinfo...

Thank you...!!

[image: screenshot_message_blank_error]

Comment: Fact that you are able to see web content means that Apache is just fine. Review error logs for PHP problems.

Comment: `Undefined variable 'pack_keys'`, seems like a PMA bug...

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sort of problem is often caused by having old files in your cache, I suggest you clear you browser's cache and perhaps clear your old cookies (which start with `pma`) to see if that helps.

Comment: sometimes it also gives error even i open it in incognito window same as normal window.